# Restrict access to certain files but not when linked from my own website

Tags: htaccess, referrer

I got a problem regarding setting my server settings so that my files can't be accessed from people linking directly to the files, but can when they click a link on my website to open the file.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://19.24.3.13/~child/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://19.24.3.13/~child/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf|doc|docx)$ /~child/ [L]
```

Problem is, when I want to open these files via my website, I get an error, because the link to the file is a direct link, something I wanted to prevent.

So to counter this, I need to let through the referrals from my own website. I tried this:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://19.24.3.13/~child/.*$" legit_referal
SetEnvIf Referer "^$" legit_referal

<LocationMatch "\.(pdf|doc|doxc)$" >
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from env=legit_referal
</LocationMatch>
```

But with no success. I get a server 500 error if I try to access it.

As you can see I use ip-adresses, because I have no domain name, only the ip.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the IP address there? It's not loading for me. Does your site have an actual domain name?

Comment: The ip address is fake. It's just standing there for example.

Comment: "server 500 error" usually means a misconfiguration or syntax error, not that your rules are not working. It shouldn't it look like this `SetEnvIf Referer "^http://yourdomain.com" legit_referal`?

Comment: Doesnt work as well. It goes wrong with the LocationMatch if I remove that the site doesnt crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is, when I want to open these files via my website, I get an error, because the link to the file is a direct link

An ordinary link *on your website* is not a direct link. If the browser is sending any referer at all then when a user clicks a link on your website then the referer is "your website". If you are not getting a referer header in this instance then "something else" is going on.

However, you probably do need to allow an empty referer for when user's browsers don't send the HTTP referer header (for whatever reason). For example, when users type the URL *directly* in their browser (this is a *direct* link), or simply hit the *reload* button - presumably you do want to allow this? If you don't allow this then it is possible that some legitimate users might have problems accessing your files.

Your first example looks pretty much OK, except that `http://19.24.3.13/~child/` looks a bit weird (this looks like the temporary URL that some shared hosts supply before the domain resolves?). However, the following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://19\.24\.3\.13
RewriteRule \.(pdf|docx?)$ - [F]
```

The above will return a 403 Forbidden for PDF, DOC and DOCX URLs when the HTTP referer is not empty AND not the current host. Note that this allows direct requests (when the HTTP Referer is empty). If you wish to prevent direct requests then omit the first `RewriteCond` directive.

Your second code block results in a 500 Internal Server Error because `LocationMatch` is not permitted in .htaccess files. You need the `Files` directive.

**UPDATE:** I'd previously included `%{HTTP_HOST}` in the *condPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) - that was a stupid mistake! Server variables are not evaluated in the *CondPattern* (a regex) so would have matched the literal string "%{HTTP_HOST}"! Which would never happen, so the condition (a negative match) would always have succeeded and the request would *always* be blocked!

Comment: I'll try it out now. Thanks for this informative answer, TIL about referrers :) I'll update soon! EDIT: Ok i tried it, it doesn't work. It lets every request through, nothing seems to be blocked. Couple other things, maybe it has some value for you. I'm running a Joomla installtion and I am trying to get it working with that. About the shared host URL, that is entirely true.

Comment: EDIT2: Something happened, I guess the cache cleared, I cannot access any documents at all. I get a Permission Denied.403: FORBIDDEN

Comment: The above directives should come immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, and I still get a permission denied error. Maybe I need to state that the site is a Joomla site, and maybe because of that it's giving these errors.

Comment: The fact that it's Joomla should not make any difference - providing these directives are at the top of your .htaccess file then we are operating outside of Joomla. However, the problem could be related to accessing the site via `<IP Address>/~child` (if that is how you are still accessing the site). What is the (PDF/DOC) URL you are requesting? What is the value of `HTTP_HOST`?

Comment: Yes that is still how I am accessin this website, is that a problem? Because if so I can get a domain for it, altough I want to try it first with this URL. I don't really want to share the direct link, because that will pop up in Google in no time. But it's somethign like 194.247.31.134/~website/images/files/report.pdf My HTTP_HOST is: 194.247.31.134

Comment: Do you have any other idea? I tried to /~child behind the HTTP_HOST but that didn't work either. You think I need to fix a domain for this problem to solve? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Accessing the site using `<IP-Address>/~child` shouldn't be a problem in this respect (however, it can certainly cause other problems). Just try typing the full URL of `report.pdf` directly into the browser address bar. Do you still get a `403 Forbidden`?

Comment: Nope, I get the PDF served like I'm logged in, but I'm not...

Comment: Ok, good. (This is outside Joomla, so whether you are logged in or not to Joomla does not make a difference.) This would imply that `HTTP_REFERER` is not being set correctly - but this is set by your browser?! Check the value of `HTTP_REFERER` when following the link. If that looks OK, then you'll probably need to paste your entire .htaccess file in your question so we can have a better look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26883/discussion-between-huub-s-and-w3d).